# How to start a script after another script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, greasemonkey, video.js

Iam trying to start my script after another script finished his work and returned rt():adv.bind to console. The script is running in an iframe. I tried it with window.addEventListener but the script still fires too early. How can I delay the start of my script to the end?

Myscript

```
window.addEventListener ("load", start, false);
function start () {
   console.log("Start - Script");
}
```

Console Log

```
unreachable code after return statement[Weitere Informationen]script.packed.2254.js:1:25167
unreachable code after return statement[Weitere Informationen]script.packed.2254.js:1:25719
unreachable code after return statement[Weitere Informationen]script.packed.2254.js:1:26637
Start – Script                                                         myscript.user.js:9:1
unreachable code after return statement[Weitere Informationen]script.packed.2254.js:1:19880
unreachable code after return statement[Weitere Informationen]script.packed.2254.js:1:20902
unreachable code after return statement[Weitere Informationen]script.packed.2254.js:1:23477
unreachable code after return statement[Weitere Informationen]                  t.js:7:3294
rt():in  true false popunder 1                                                 t.js:12:2056
rt():adv.bind                                                                  t.js:12:2106
```

Situation

I have a website with an embedded videojs player and iam trying to start the video automatically after loading the site. The player and my script are running inside an iframe otherwise I can't use the functions

```
document.querySelector('#videooverlay').click();
olvideo.player.play();
```

It's working already in chrome but in FF the player starts loading and stops a few seconds later. I thought maybe FF needs longer to load the site and the player isn't ready when I call the function. So if I can delay my script after the rt():advbind I would know if this is the problem.

Comment: maybe the other scripts are runned async

Comment: Er, you need to listen for `load` event on the script element.

Comment: You would generally sequence scripts using callbacks, but iframes run in a separate context and mostly can't interact with the outside page. IFrames are meant to insulate between different runtimes, so that's going to be a problem for you here. If both scripts are in the iframe (or both are out) you'd pass function A as an argument to function B. Function B would run, and then when it's done, it would run the passed-in function A. Look up callbacks. It's important to know whether the iframe is relevant here. Maybe you could explain that a bit more.

Comment: Considering this is tagged Greasmonkey and you mention iframe and running a script after another one....you need to provide a lot more detail into exactly what is going on here. See [mcve] Nobody can guess what you are trying to do or why it is throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout to delay your script

Comment: I tryed to use setTimeout but its not working. If i use setTimeout like this

Comment: window.setTimeout(delay, 5000);
function delay()
{
console.log("Delay");
}
nothing happen.